# SubSonic and not default connection string problem

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I encountered bug in my programm because of SubSonic3 returns records with default connection string in

```
SingleOrDefault(ByVal expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Company.filter, Boolean)), ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal providerName As String)
```

In Subsonic sources, Database.cs line 323:

```
instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

I think that was the cause of problem in my case. It creates instance with default constructor and then returns it as a result, that's where we loose custom connection string.

Personally I fixed it with adding 2 lines to ActiveRecord.tt template, in SingleOrDefault function, which has connectionString argument:

```
            single._db=new <#=Namespace#>.<#=DatabaseName#>DB(connectionString, providerName);
            single._repo = new SubSonicRepository<<#=tbl.ClassName#>>(single._db);
```

But I think you should examine this problem deeper, Rob :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow. You specify the name of the ConnectionString is Settings.tt - that's the one we use.

Comment: Yes, but it's default connection string. And SingleOrDefault function called with custom ConnectionString parameter returns record, that point to the wrong database.
For example, I have several databases, which has identical structure, but they used separately. Lets say I have Company1 and Company2 databases. If I use record.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name="joe", GetConnectionStringForCompany2, ProviderName) it will return me record object that is pointing to the Company1 database, but I passed connection string for Company2 database. I hope that illustrates the situation.